# Hide a section with JS with document.getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

I cannot find where is my mystake. I try to hide this section (i.e. survey1) in HTML through JS. Could you please help me? Thanks

Here is my code in html

```
<section id="survey1" class="survey1">

        <ul class="meta2">
                <li class="icon2 fa-clock-o">2 min.</li>
                <li class="icon2 fa-gift"><a href="#">1 point</a></li>

        </ul>       


 <nav id="banner2"> 
     <li>  <a href="survey.html" class="button2"> Go </a> </li>
     <li>  Sondage 1 sur le développement personnel<br/></li>


 </nav>
</section>
```

Here is my code in CSS

```
.hidden {
  display: none;}
```

Here is my code in JS

```
classv= document.getElementsByClassName('survey1');
classv.className='hidden';
```

Comment: getElementsByClassName should return you a collection... you could just use getElementById

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `getElementsByClassName()` gives you a `HTMLCollection`, a collection of `Node`s. So if there's only one node in it, you can very well use `[0]`:

```
classv = document.getElementsByClassName('survey1');
classv[0].className = 'hidden';
```

I would recommend using `.classList.add()`:

```
classv[0].classList.add('hidden');
```

So that if you wanna remove it, you can do so by using:

```
classv[0].classList.remove('hidden');
```